# Group action on fibre functor

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, group-actions, abelian-categories, functors

Let $C$ be a Tannakian category (ie. it is rigid tensor Abelian category where hom sets are $k$-vector spaces and there is a fibre functor $w$ from $C$ to category of vector spaces such that $w$ is a exact faithful tensor functor.)

Let group $G$ act on $C$ in the sense that for each $g \in G$ we have a functor $a_g : C \to C$ such that $a_g a_h$ and $a_{gh}$ are naturally isomorphic. Further assume the group acts by tensor functors.

> Simpson in his paper "Higgs Bundles and Local Systems" says that "by transport of structure, $G$ also acts on ${\rm End}(w,C)$ where the endomorphism algebra is just the endomorphism of the fibre functor."

> My question is : How do we get such an action?

A typical element in ${\rm End}(w,C)$ is a tuple ${f_V}$ where $f_V \in{\rm End}(w(V))$ and makes required diagrams commute. (It's just the data of natural transformation nothing else).

Comment: have you tried  to ask this question at mathoverflow ?

Comment: Now posted at MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419129/group-action-on-fibre-functor